# Substituir parte de string por drawable ou imagem

Tags: java, android

Recebo do banco de dados uma string em em formarto "texto texto texto ??? texto texto" e preciso transformar o "???" em uma imagem ou algum caracter, o ideal seria uma imagem ou drawable que posso personalizar melhor.
Pelo que vi o replace só funciona com string, então estou sem direção para seguir.

A ideia é mais ou menos essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insira uma [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) num [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

O ImageSpan é construído com o drawable a inserir e o SpannableString com o texto onde ele será inserido.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String text = "texto ? texto";

    //Posição onde colocar a imegem(posição da marca)
    int imagePos = text.indexOf("?");

    //Criar um SpannableString do texto
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);

    //Obter o drawable a inserir
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    //Criar um ImageSpan do drawable
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);

    //Inserir a imagem(ImageSpan) no texto(SpannableString)
    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan,imagePos,imagePos+1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    //Atribuir o texto com a imagem ao TextView
    textView.setText(spannableString);
}
```

O principio é este. Ajuste às sua necessidades.

Comment: Apenas na hora de criar os spannablestring colocar o a string sem a marca, de resto funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: começou da erro IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (51 ... 52) ends beyond length 51

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: e para eu substituir "???" no lugar de "?" como faço?

Comment: pois alterei onde esta "?" e o resultado ficou imagem+??

Comment: Tem de eliminar os "?" excedentes.

Comment: Ja que eu que estou desenvolvendo o backend, vou trocar o caracte pra ficar mais simples. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Bom eu costumo usar fromHtml() para mostrar um texto formatado como em html em um text view, dê uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617210/android-html-fromhtml-with-images a pessoa mostra como fazer para exibir texto e imagem no text view